# while loop in javascript produce redundant output

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Just wonder why the output by the while loop contains two "10".

```
var j=1;
while( j < 11){
    console.log(j);
    j ++;
}
```

The output looks like below
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10

Just mention that do-while loop could produce similar problems, which helps to understand the nature of the last output.

```
var k=0
do{
    console.log("do-while");
    k++;
}while(k<10)
```

The output is like that:
do-while
do-while
do-while
do-while
do-while
do-while
do-while
do-while
do-while
do-while
9

Comment: It doesn't here https://jsfiddle.net/xnh6nsgp/

Comment: perhaps there's another `console.log` you forgot about

Comment: Are you running this directly in the console?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be talking about JS Console's output or something similar?

First ten outputs (numbers form 1 to 10) are printed by the console.log command you have in your code.

And the last one is what "while" expression returns, and it's a last line of "while" block.

You can easier understand it if you read your code like:

```
var j=1;
while( j < 11){
    console.log(j);
    j++;
}
return j;
```